# Magnetic moment of carbon

Tags: condensed-matter, atomic-physics, semiconductor-physics, physical-chemistry, ferromagnetism

I read recently the magnetic moment of carbon is zero. I am surprised how is this possible because the electronic configuration of it is $1s^2 2s^2 2p^2$. So we have two unpaired electrons here.
I'll be very thankful for clarifying this doubt.

Answer (score 3):

You need to consider not a single carbon atom,
but the solid (i.e. graphite or diamond) consisting
of many carbon atoms.
There are bonds between neigboring carbon atoms.

[image]
<sub>(screenshot from video "[AP Chemistry Electron Configuration and Magnetism](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-8pk3XxDJPM&t=622s)")</sub>

Each such bond is made up by 2 electrons
(both neighboring atoms contributing one of its
$2s$ or $2p$ electrons to this bond).
These two electrons form kind of a pair
located between the 2 atoms.
So at the end there are no unpaired electrons
in a carbon solid.
And that's why carbon is not ferromagnetic,
but only diamagnetic (like most chemical elements).